# How can I get the dowload url from images that are resized with firestorage image-resize extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-extensions

- I am able to download the url from the original uploaded file
- I am not able to download the url from the files that are created by the image resize extention.

```
//making a ref beforehand
const ref = db.collection("impressions").doc().id;

//upload the original file
const bucket = await firebase.storage().ref("impressions/" + ref).put(image);

//this works but I do not need it
const downloadUrl = await firebase.storage().ref("impressions/" + ref).getDownloadURL();

//trying to retrieve the downloadUrl from the files that are most likely still in the process of being created by the image resize extention?
//the ref's are correct

const downloadUrl_image = await firebase.storage().ref("impressions/" + ref + "_1000x1000").getDownloadURL();

const downloadUrl_thumb = await firebase.storage().ref("impressions/" + ref + "_50x50").getDownloadURL();
```

How can I get the download url from the resized images? Is there an event I can listen to? Or do I need to make my own function?

Thank you for the help,

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase extensions are really great because they allow you to rapidly deploy a standard business logic but they might be limited in terms of configuration options.

In particular, you will not be able to get, out-of-the-box, the download urls of the resized images.

I can think of two possible approaches:

#### 1. Trigger a Cloud Function on resized image creation

During the Extension configuration, you define the path in which to store resized images.

The help says:

> For example, if you specify a path of `thumbs` and you upload an
>   image to `/images/original.jpg`, then the resized image is stored at
>   `/images/thumbs/original_200x200.jpg`.

So, you know upfront the structure of the path and the names of the resized images. You could therefore trigger a Cloud Function when these files are created, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events). You could, for example, store the download url of an image in a Firestore document with the same id than the resized image file name (or the original file name)

#### 2. Write your own Image Resizing Cloud Function

There is a sample within the official Cloud Function samples Collection that does exactly the same than the extension. You will find it [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) on Github. You can also look at [the code of the Extension itself](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/next/storage-resize-images/functions/src/index.ts).

This way you'll have full control on the Cloud Function logic.

Comment: Could you look into this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740953/resize-image-before-upload-in-reactjs/61741009#61741009

Comment: @newdeveloper Hello, sorry I cannot help you, as I am not versed in the technologies implied in your question.