# How To Resize Image Before Uploading to Firebase Storage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to resize the image that my users upload to keep my website more efficient and limit my  storage usage.

I have created a function called resizeFile from the package `"react-image-file-resizer"`

Now what i am struggling with is how would i resize the image before it gets uploaded to firebase storage?

Here is my code:

```
const resizeFile = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 500, 500, "JPEG", 100, 0, (uri) => {
      resolve(uri);
    });
  });

const addProperty = async () => {
      if (
        !propName ||
     
      
      ) {
        alert("Please Enter All Required Data");
      } else {
        await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("Properties")
          .add({
            propname: propName,
        
          })
          .then(async (result) => {
            await Promise.all(
              selectedImages.map(async (image) => {
                const uri = await resizeFile(image);// i dont know what to do after this point
                console.log(uri);
                const storageRef = storage.ref(
                  `propertyImages/${result.id}/${image.name}`
                );
                storageRef.put(uri).then((urls) => {
                  console.log(urls);
                  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then( (downloadUrls) => {
                    console.log(downloadUrls);
                     firebase
                     .firestore()
                      .collection("Properties")
                      .doc(result.id)
                      .update({
                        propertyID: result.id,
                        imageUrls: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(downloadUrls)
                      })
                      .then((res) => {
                        //handleUploadChange();
                        // alert("Property Added Successfully");
                        // window.location.reload();
                      });
                  });
                });
              })
            );
          });
      }
    };
```

EDIT:

Okay i managed to some how solve the issue, but there is still one problem which is that the height never gets resized to my specified maxHeight for some reason. Why is that?

Here is what i modified:

```
await Promise.all(
              selectedImages.map(async (image) => {
                const uri = await resizeFile(image);
                console.log(uri);
                const storageRef = storage.ref(
                  `propertyImages/${result.id}/${image.name}`
                );
                storageRef.putString(uri,'data_url').then((urls) => {
                  console.log(urls);
                  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then( (downloadUrls) => {
                    console.log(downloadUrls);
                     firebase
                     .firestore()
                      .collection("Properties")
                      .doc(result.id)
                      .update({
                        propertyID: result.id,
                        imageUrls: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(downloadUrls)
                      })
                      .then((res) => {
                        //handleUploadChange();
                        // alert("Property Added Successfully");
                        // window.location.reload();
                      });
                  });
                });
              })
            );
```

Comment: Is your issue with firebase or with "react-image-file-resizer" ? You should check if your image is resized correctly on your front-end first. Also can you give an exemple of "one problem which is that the height never gets resized to my specified maxHeight" ?

Comment: I'm removing the firebase tags from this question because the issue doesn't appear to be about Firebase products.  It's about image resizing prior to Firebase being involved.  If you feel the problem is related to your use of Firebase, please edit the question to explain what you're observing that others who use Firebase can reproduce.

Comment: @DougStevenson it does have something to do with firebase as I WANT to resize before uploading to firebase storage. and I WANT to update my  FIREBASE FIRESTORE DATABASE after uploading. Please add the tags back or try to solve the problem with me

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier it is with both, it is intertwined. I need both together, I need to resize and only then upload to firebase storage. This is the main issue that I explained above.

Comment: Wanting to do something with the resized image isn't part of the first problem here.  The first problem is resizing.  Once you do that, you have a second task for uploading it to Firebase.  On Stack Overflow, it's only allowed to ask one question at a time.  Firebase can come later after you've solved the first problem.  Let's focus this question on the resizing so you can get help with that easier.  Then ask another question about Firebase if you get stuck on that later.  I strongly suggest editing the question to focus on that first problem so you can get better help.

Comment: motionless , I think @DougStevenson is still right, the second snippet is the solution for firebase, as a solution it should be an answer to this question (and not in the question itself). If you want peoples to help solve the issue with the image resize, it would be helpful to show the code only related to the resize. (without the firebase part) (you need a third snippet now). But I am sure you can see this elongated question will hurt your visibility and potential to get helper to read.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier That is not correct, if you can see my posted answer, the solution to the problem is to use .putString() which is a firebase storage function. did not read my question carefully, or did not even read my question and just assumed it had nothing to do with firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please read my posted question and answer carefully. You'll see that you were mistaken about the firebase tags and I will add them back. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the firebase and image resizing issue this way. It turned out that the package does resize and compress the image to whatever you are specifying but if the image was of another format such as png (since i specified JPEG) it wouldn't resize it exactly to your liking. However, someone in the comments suggested that it wasnt related to firebase and it was solved by a firebase function.

all i had to do is to use .putString() so that the base64 returned would be converted to a string in firebase storage. Therefore, the answer to my question actually had a huge link to firebase and firebase storage.

```
const resizeFile = file =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 500, 500, "JPEG", 25, 0, uri => {
      resolve(uri);
    });
  });

const addProperty = async () => {
  if (
    !propName ||
    !price ||
    !bedroom ||
    !bathroom ||
    !area ||
    !type ||
    !category ||
    !features ||
    !services
  ) {
    alert("Please Enter All Required Data");
  } else {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Properties")
      .add({
        propname: propName,
        price: price,
        bedrooms: bedroom,
        bathroom: bathroom,
        exclusive: exclusive,
        area: area,
        type: type,
        category: category,
        features: features,
        services: services,
        summary: summary,
        location: location,
        salesAgentID: salesAgent,
        date: getCurrentDate(),
      })
      .then(async result => {
        await Promise.all(
          selectedImages.map(async image => {
            const uri = await resizeFile(image);
            const storageRef = storage.ref(
              `propertyImages/${result.id}/${image.name}`
            );
            storageRef.putString(uri, "data_url").then(urls => {
              storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrls => {
                console.log(downloadUrls);
                firebase
                  .firestore()
                  .collection("Properties")
                  .doc(result.id)
                  .update({
                    propertyID: result.id,
                    imageUrls:
                      firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                        downloadUrls
                      ),
                  })
                  .then(res => {
                    setIsUploaded("Uploaded success");

                    //handleUploadChange();
                    // alert("Property Added Successfully");
                    // window.location.reload();
                  });
              });
            });
          })
        );
      });
  }
};
```